# Tiny Death Star keeps crashing - anything I can do to save it?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

So I have been playing tiny Death Star religiously for the past couple of months and I managed to get 99 levels and upgraded my elevator to the turbo one for 125 bux, I was fairly far along. I had even decorated 60 levels to unlock the overbridge. The other day I was playing when I noticed that all of the remaining levels only cost 1 bux to unlock, I thought it was a promotion and quickly snapped up all the levels. Soon afterward my game crashed and I've not been able to boot it since. I've tried restarting the iPad, closing out the game, turning off the iPad, turning off the wifi, switching from online to local and vise versa, nothing works. I really don't want to delete and reinstall the game because it seems there's no way to save it with gamecenter. Is there anything I can do to salvage it?

*I haven't linked it to Facebook yet but now I obviously can't do so in game... Is there a way to do it through fb and gamecenter or does it have to be in game to save progress?

Comment: Same exact thing happened to me, if you haven't linked it to facebook you will lose all your progress if you delete it like I did. How to fix the crash I am not exactly sure

Comment: Exact same situation here. I deleted the game and started over and the same thing happened again. I'm glad I didn't spend ony cash on the game this time.

Comment: Is your iPad jailbroken by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a similar problem, from about mid-March the app would crash upon launching for me under iOS on an iPad 2.  That was right after the "many levels acquired cheaply" period. I saw that many others had similar problems and stopped playing, obviously, as it crashed upon launch. However, the most recent update 1.4.2 (of Aug 7th 2014) worked well for me, first under iOS 6 and now under iOS 7 with all my earlier progress restored.  This was all without any Facebook connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the iOS version of the game is the same as the one for Android or not but on Android I have linked my Google and Facebook accounts so it saves my progress online. If I get a new phone or reinstall the app I can just re link my accounts then close and open the app again and it will ask if I want to play the save online or the local save.  But be careful if you choose the wrong one it will overwrite the other, but it does ask you to confirm so not much room for error.

So saying all that, if you have linked your Facebook or some other account to the app you may be able to uninstall and reinstall it to fix the non opening glitch and hopefully resign in to your account and recover your progress.  I hope you don't lose everything, definitely a fun game.

Answer (score 0):

"The other day I was playing when I noticed that all of the remaining levels only cost 1 bux to unlock, I thought it was a promotion and quickly snapped up all the levels. Soon afterward my game crashed and I've not been able to boot it since."  Same thing here.  Have tried everything to get it to load, rebooting phone, disconnecting Facebook, clearing out memory on my iPhone, nothing.  I was over 100 levels already and maxing out the remaining levels I still had to get for the 1 bux has just crashed it.  I hate the idea of starting over and losing everything by deleting the game, and would rather just quit playing until they come out with an update that will fix it.  I'm quite disgusted actually.

Comment: I did the same thing and nothing I could to recover it, had to start over, sorry for the bad new. If you can't support they will cover and purchases you may have made.